# What is the term for a CPU cache that can hit during a fill?

Tags: cpu-cache

Years back I worked with an ARM system with a custom vendor-designed cache controller that tracked validity with a bit-per-byte for each cacheline. It used this for two purposes: writes did not require a fill on miss, and reads could be satisfied as soon as the available bytes were filled into the cache(with varying latency depending on address inside  the cacheline). I no longer have access to them or their documentation.

Is there a general term for handling a load from cache during a fill?